# How to convert a Java String to an ASCII byte array?

Tags: java, string, ascii, arrays

How to convert a Java String to an ASCII byte array?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Using the [`getBytes`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)) method, giving it the appropriate [`Charset`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) (or `Charset` name).

Example:

```
String s = "Hello, there.";
byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

---

If more control is required (such as throwing an exception when a character outside the 7 bit US-ASCII is encountered) then `CharsetDecoder` can be used:

```
private static byte[] strictStringToBytes(String s, Charset charset) throws CharacterCodingException {
    ByteBuffer x  = charset.newEncoder().onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT).encode(CharBuffer.wrap(s));
    byte[] b = new byte[x.remaining()];
    x.get(b);
    return b;
 }
```

---

Before Java 7 it is possible to use: `byte[] b = s.getBytes("US-ASCII");`. The enum `StandardCharsets`, the encoder as well as the specialized `getBytes(Charset)` methods have been introduced in Java 7.

Comment: I'm mildly embarrassed by how easy that was.

Comment: This will convert unmappable characters like '\u00e0' (&agrave;) into '?'. It would be nicer to have a method that converts that into 'a'.

Comment: For people using Java 7 or later, use the class [StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) which contains some constants for standard charsets. `byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);`

Comment: `getBytes(Charset)` introduced in [Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)).

Answer (score 23):

If you are a [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) user there is a handy [`Charsets`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html) class:

```
String s = "Hello, world!";
byte[] b = s.getBytes(Charsets.US_ASCII);
```

Apart from not hard-coding arbitrary charset name in your source code it has a much bigger advantage: [`Charsets.US_ASCII`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html#US_ASCII) is of `Charset` type (not `String`) so you avoid checked [`UnsupportedEncodingException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/UnsupportedEncodingException.html) thrown only from [`String.getBytes(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)), but not from [`String.getBytes(Charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)).

In Java 7 there is equivalent [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) class.

Comment: sadly, `String.getBytes(Charset)` was not added until API 9 :( So if you want to target Froyo and above, you can't do that.

Answer (score 5):

```
String s = "ASCII Text";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

Answer (score 5):

There is only one character wrong in the code you tried:

```
Charset characterSet = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
String string = "Wazzup";
byte[] bytes = String.getBytes(characterSet);
               ^
```

Notice the upper case "String". This tries to invoke a static method on the string class, which does not exist. Instead you need to invoke the method on your string instance:

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes(characterSet);
```

Comment: if so , can you please tell me how could it be that an hebrew letter is taken 1 byte (ascii encoding) , it even doesnt exists in the ascii. and it is not using default encodung since i specified manually.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/5WPD3.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir: This might be better posted as a new question, but the reason is that character is not encodable in US-ASCII and the `getBytes(Charset)` method is specified to replace characters that can not be encoded. With US-ASCII, this replacement char is the question mark, so your byte array contains one element with the ASCII value of '?' (63).

Answer (score 5):

The problem with other proposed solutions is that they will either drop characters that cannot be directly mapped to ASCII, or replace them with a marker character like `?`.

You might desire to have for example accented characters converted to that same character without the accent. There are a couple of tricks to do this (including building a static mapping table yourself or leveraging existing 'normalization' defined for unicode), but those methods are far from complete.

Your best bet is using the [junidecode](http://www.ippatsuman.com/projects/junidecode/index.html) library, which cannot be complete either but incorporates a lot of experience in the most sane way of transliterating Unicode to ASCII.

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to need this in Android and want to make it work with anything older than FroYo, you can also use [EncodingUtils.getAsciiBytes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EncodingUtils.html#getAsciiBytes%28java.lang.String%29):

```
byte[] bytes = EncodingUtils.getAsciiBytes("ASCII Text");
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty good tip! On Android getBytes(...) does NOT work properly even on ICS+

Comment: I can't find EncodingUtils anywhere?

Comment: @behelit if you follow my link it redirects to this bit: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Basically saying that you need to manually include the Apache HTTP library  as it's deprecated now.

Comment: But if you're just looking for the docs, searching for "apache http encodingutils" gives some useful results like: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EncodingUtils.html

Answer (score 4):

In my string I have Thai characters (TIS620 encoded) and German umlauts. The answer from agiles put me on the right path. Instead of .getBytes() I use now

```
  int len = mString.length(); // Length of the string
  byte[] dataset = new byte[len];
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
     char c = mString.charAt(i);
     dataset[i]= (byte) c;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe a little bit late but this worked perfectly for me (Trying to convert German UTF-8 Special Characters to ASCII). Thank you very much! You made my day :D

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to ascii values.

```
   String test = "ABCD";

   for ( int i = 0; i < test.length(); ++i ) {
   char c = test.charAt( i );
   int j = (int) c;
   System.out.println(j);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Actually Base64 class is not available in Android. Link is given below for more information.

```
byte[] byteArray;                                                  
     byteArray= json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    String encoded=Base64.encodeBytes(byteArray);
    userLogin(encoded);
```

Here is the link for Base64 class: http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html

Answer (score 0):

To convert String to ASCII byte array:

```
String s1 = "Hello World!";
byte[] byteArray = s1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
// Now byteArray is [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]
```

To convert ASCII byte array to String:

```
String s2 = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @(#)demo1.java
 *
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2012/8/30
 */

import java.util.*;

public class demo1 
{
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    String str;
    int key;

    void getdata()
    {
        System.out.println ("plase enter a string");
        str=s.next();
        System.out.println ("plase enter a key");
        key=s.nextInt();
    }

    void display()
    {
        char a;
        int j;
        for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i )
        {

            char c = str.charAt( i );
            j = (int) c + key;
            a= (char) j;

            System.out.print(a);  
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            demo1 obj=new demo1();
            obj.getdata();
            obj.display();
        }
    }
}
```