# Print String as Bytes

Tags: java, string, printing, byte

Can somebody tell me how to print a string as bytes i.e. its corresponding ASCII code?!

My input is a normal string like "9" and the output should be the corresponding ASCII value of character '9'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.getBytes()` method.

```
byte []bytes="Hello".getBytes();
for(byte b:bytes)
  System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: Works great for ASCII, but if you run into the eight-bit-half, you will have negative numbers, because the powers that be decided that bytes in Java are signed.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a Byte Array - see this question: [How to convert a Java String to an ASCII byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688042/how-to-convert-a-java-string-to-an-ascii-byte-array)

To get the ascii value of each individual character you can do:

```
String s = "Some string here";

for (int i=0; i<s.length();i++)
  System.out.println("ASCII value of: "+s.charAt(i) + " is:"+ (int)s.charAt(i) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am not sure what do you want but may be the following method helps to print it .

```
    String str = "9";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(str.charAt(i) + " ASCII " + (int) str.charAt(i));
    }
```

you can see it at http://www.java-forums.org/java-tips/5591-printing-ascii-values-characters.html

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach would be:

1. You can iterate through a byte array:

   `final byte[] bytes = "FooBar".getBytes();
   for (byte b : bytes) {
     System.out.print(b + " ");
   }`

   > Result: 70 111 111 66 97 114
2. or, through a char array and convert the char into primitive int

   `for (final char c : "FooBar".toCharArray()) {
     System.out.print((int) c + " ");
   }`

   > Result: 70 111 111 66 97 114
3. or, thanks to Java8, with a forEach through the inputSteam:
   `"FooBar".chars().forEach(c -> System.out.print(c + " "));`

   > Result: 70 111 111 66 97 114
4. or, thanks to Java8 and [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/lang/):
   `final List<Byte> list = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject("FooBar".getBytes()));
   list.forEach(b -> System.out.print(b + " "));`

   > Result: 70 111 111 66 97 114

A better approach would use the [charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) (ASCII, UTF-8, ...):

```
// Convert a String to byte array (byte[])
final String str = "FooBar";
final byte[] arrayUtf8 = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
for(final byte b: arrayUtf8){
  System.out.println(b + " ");
}
```

> Result: 70 111 111 66 97 114

```
final byte[] arrayUtf16 = str.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
  for(final byte b: arrayUtf16){
System.out.println(b);
}
```

> Result: 70 0 111 0 111 0 66 0 97 0 114

Hope it has helped.