# How would you convert a string to a 64 bit integer?

Tags: java, seed

I am making an application that involves a seed to generate a world and some games let you provide that seed with text.  I'm wondering how would you 'convert' a string to an integer.

A simple way would be to use the ASCII values of all the characters and append them to a string which you would then parse to an integer, but that severely limits the size of the string.  How would you be able to do this with a larger string?

EDIT: 64 bit not 32

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688042/how-to-convert-a-java-string-to-an-ascii-byte-array

Comment: I would suggest a cryptographic hash of the bytes of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just call `String.hashcode()`.  The standard `String.hashcode()` function makes use of all characters in the target string and gives good dispersal.

The only thing I would question is whether 32 bits of seed is going to be enough.  It *might* mean that your world generator could generate at most 2<sup>32</sup> different worlds.

Answer (score 4):

Random seeds for `Random` can be at least 48-bit, ideally 64-bit.  You can write your own hash code like this.

```
public static long hashFor(String s) {
   long h = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
       h = h * 10191 + s.charAt(i);
   return h;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Standard way for converting a String to Integer is using Integer.parseInt(String);
You pass the string into this and it would convert the String to int. Try it and let me know!

Comment: So what happens if you do `Integer.parseInt("abcdefgh13uhfds")`?