# Byte length of string in different character sets

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I need to find out the length of a string for different character sets in Java. Assuming that I have 160 characters and the ASCII character set, the byte length should be 140.
Similarly I need for other character set also.

I may get an input stream in any of the character set, but once received it will be stored in UTF-16 and subsequently I will not be able to get the exact byte length of original character set.

Comment: You could [convert it to bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688042/how-to-convert-a-java-string-to-an-ascii-byte-array) and just invoke .length?

Comment: There you are, @Duncan

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688042/how-to-convert-a-java-string-to-an-ascii-byte-array) to convert the String to bytes (tl;dr use .getBytes()) and then invoke the .length property to get the number of bytes in the String.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution is not suitable for handling 7 bit ASCII character set or UTF-7 . In UTF-7 every characters in the stream represented in 7 bits not 8 bits. so we can send 160 characters in 140 bytes using UTF-7 Character Encoding . But while using getBytes("UTF-7").length function on inputString of 160 characters we get 160 Bytes instead of 140 Bytes.